# Mongoose Schema Of Nested Objects

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Is there any way to create schema for this type data:

```
 "documents" : {

            "54983c4c78c824eb0ac7a0d8" : {
                "completed" : true
            },
            "54983c4c78c824eb0ac7a0dd" : {
                "completed" : true
            },
            "54983c4c78c824eb0ac7a0d7" : {
                "completed" : true
            },
            "54983c4c78c824eb0ac7a0de" : {
                "completed" : true,
                "comments" : [ 
                    {
                        "author" : "54973a31cfb18d60089e9403",
                        "text" : "hello"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
```

Comment: Yes. But don't do that. Never use "data" as "keys" as you are here. Use "arrays" instead. It's much more logical.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
"documents":{[
             {"id":54983c4c78c824eb0ac7a0d8,
             "status":"completed"},
             {"id":54983c4c78c824eb0ac7a0dd,
             "status":"completed"},
             {"id":54983c4c78c824eb0ac7a0d7,
             "status":"completed"},
             {"id":54983c4c78c824eb0ac7a0de,
             "status":"completed",
             "comments":[
                         {"author_id":54973a31cfb18d60089e9403,
                          "text":"hello"}]
             }]}
```

Then you could query anything you want:

```
db.documents.find({"id":54983c4c78c824eb0ac7a0d8})
```

or by status:

```
db.documents.find({"status":"completed"})
```